# Swift Setting Textfield's Placeholders Programmatically

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, textfield, placeholder

I'm currently trying to figure out how to set the placeholder text of a textfield. The text field is within a cell. The text I would like to assign to the placeholder is contained in an array.

I previously did a similar thing with setting images, and that looked like this

```
cell?.imageView?.image = row1images[indexPath.row]
```

So, using that ideology I thought using...

```
cell?.textField?.text = nil
cell?.textField?.placeholder = row1[indexPath.row]
```

... would work. However, I get the error "Value of type ‘UITableViewCell’ has no member 'textField'"

Comment: `UITableViewCell` does not have a text field, hence the error. Perhaps `cell` should be declared as the actual type of your custom cell.

Comment: Have you created custom cell? Show full code of `cellforrowatindexpath`.

Comment: You have two option to set TextFiled placeholder : [**TextField PlaceHolder**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-change-uitexefield-placeholder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

If u have a textField on a custom cell, then add this following code inside cellForRowAt function.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

            cell .yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: row1[indexPath.row],
                                                                       attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black])


            return cell
    }
```

Comment: I get an error that reads, "Use of undeclared type "CustomTableViewCell"

Answer (score 0):

The error **"Value of type ‘UITableViewCell’ has no member 'textField'"** says it all. Either you have used a `prototype cell` that doesn't know anything about your `TextField` or you have used your `custom cell` but haven't changed it's class to your `CustomCellClass`. Besides, you may have casted your `reusable cell` as `UITableViewCell` other than your `CustomCellClass`.

Fix these issues, your code is okay.